Behaviour of $a^k\pmod b,\ k=1,2,3,\ldots$

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Suppose $\left(x_k\right)_{k=1}^{n}$ is a
$k-$tuple of $-1$'s and $1$'s. Let (the function) $r(i,j)$ be the
remainder when $i$ is divided by $j,$ so that $0\leq r(i,j) \leq j-1.$
Prove is disprove:
$\exists\ a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ such that, $\forall\ k\in
 \{1,2,\ldots, n-1\},$
$$ \text{sgn } \left(r\left(a^{k+1},b\right) - r\left(a^k,b\right) \right) =  \text{sgn } \left( x_k \right),$$
where $\text{sgn }$ is the signum function.

This wouldn't work if the question was for,
$$ \text{sgn } \left(r\left((k+1)a,b\right) - r\left(ka,b\right) \right) =  \text{sgn } \left( x_k \right),$$
for then $\left(x_k\right)_{k=1}^{4} = (1,1,-1,-1)$ is a counter-example.
I imagine the answer to my question is yes, but I don't know how to prove it. Fermat's Little theorem could be useful.
Progress:
As Thomas Andrews pointed out in the comments, it is easy to solve it for all $x_k=1:$ just take $b=a^n+1.$
Next, I found a general example where $x_k=-1$ for all $k.$ Let $t$ be any integer. Then $(t^2-t+1)^k \equiv -kt+1 \pmod {t^2}.$ For example, If $t=100,$ then we have: $9801, 9701, 9601, \ldots$ for the first few values of $(t^2-t+1)^k\pmod {t^2}.$

It is easy to solve it first for all $x_k=1,$ just take $b=a^n+1.$ Next thing to try is all $x_k=-1.$

Another way to write it is  the sign of $r(a^{k+1},b)-r(a^{k},b)$ is the sign of $x_k.$

In general, merely by heuristics, it seems like you might want $b>2^{n},$ because  then you get enough possible $a$ values. If we also assume $b$ is prime, it might be easier. The heuristic is just that we treating the sign sequence  associated with $a$ to essentially be random.

For example, modulo $71$ we get all $n=4$ examples for some $a.$ If we are trying to get all $2^n$ examples from the same $b$ prime, and we treat it as a random process, we get $b-2$ sequences,and this is an example of the coupon problem. We expect to need $b>2^nH_{2^n}\approx n2^n\log 2.$

When $n=5,$ the smallest prime which works is $383.$ This is a bit bigger than $5\cdot 2^5\ln 2\approx 111.$ This is because the coupons appear to have different probabilities. For example, $(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)$ is often missed.

If we pick a random sequence of $n+1$ distinct numbers from $1$ to $p-1,$ the odds that they will be in reverse sorted order is $1/(n+1)!.$ This turns out to be a good probability for getting $(-1,-1,\dots,-1).$ For example, when $p=9967, n=3,$ $4.4%$ of the $a$ from $2$ to $p-1$ give a decreasing sequence. When $n=4,$ they are $0.8%$ and when $n=6,$ they are $0.2%.$

This gives a new heuristic upper bound for finding prime $p$ that satisfies all $n$-sequences for some $a,$ namely $p\sim \frac{n\cdot n!}e.$

The fundamental reason this will be a difficult problem is the there isn't really a natural order to modular arithmetic. The ring $\mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z$ cannot be linearly ordered in an intuitive way that is useful. $2$ in this ring really represents $2,2\pm b,2\pm2b,\dots$ and $3$ is $3,3\pm b,3\pm 2b,\dots,$ and which representative from these two classes we choose can not be consistently ordered.

If $n=8,$ we can choose $b=524287,$ we can find an $a$ for each $2^8$ sequences. I got an off by one error in tthe comment above - for $n$ there should be such a $b$ with $b\approx (n+1)\cdot (n+1)!/e.$ Probably can find a significantly smaller one.

In any event, I suspect your conjecture is true, but proving it might be very hard because this has some of the smell of other intractable problems.

Can I cross-post this onto mathoverflow?
